How can i get current page index from PrimeNG table
I use the PrimeNg library and the Table component with paginator enabled. The Django backend application uses PageNumberPagination. How can I get the current page number from this component?
<p-table
    [value]="rows"
    [paginator]="true"
    [rows]="10"
></p-table>

@Component({
    selector: 'app-table',
    templateUrl: 'table.html',
    standalone: true,
    imports: [TableModule, CommonModule],
    providers: [ApiService]
})
export class TablePaginatorBasicDemo {
    rows!: Row[];

    constructor(private apiService: ApiService) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.apiService.getRows().pipe(tap((rows) => ({this.rows = rows}))).subscribe();
    }
}


If my answer solved the issue please accept it. Thank you.

You can try this:
component.ts:
  readonly ROWS_PER_PAGE = 5;
  currentPage = 0;
  
  updateCurrentPage(first: number): void {
    this.currentPage = first / this.ROWS_PER_PAGE;
    console.log('current page changed to: ', this.currentPage + 1);
  }

component.template.html:
  <p-table
    responsiveLayout="scroll"
    [value]="products"
    [paginator]="true"
    [rows]="ROWS_PER_PAGE"
    (firstChange)="updateCurrentPage($event)"
  >

this.currentPage contains the current page as index (starting at 0).
Stackblitz
Optionally: If you want to change the page of the paginator programmatically, you can consider this discussion of stackoverflow:
PrimeNG: How to programmatically change the selected page in paginator?
